# Websocket connection disconnects just after handshake

Tags: django, chat, django-channels

```
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/ [127.0.0.1:54395]
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/ [127.0.0.1:54395]
```

My websockets gets disconnected after handshaking. Please suggest a solution or a tutorial that can be followed to implement a basic chat functionality using channels in django.

My code:

```
class Experience(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
    
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        username = text_data_json['username']

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chatroom_message',
                'message': message,
                'username': username,
            }
        )

    async def chatroom_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        username = event['username']

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'username': username,
        }))

    pass
```

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', Experience.as_asgi()),
]
```

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  'http': asgi_app,
  'websocket':  AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            websocket_urlpatterns
        )),  # new
})

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("localhost", 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, by connecting to `/ws/` you are trying to connect to not existing route. Since it's not specifyed, server disconnects you.

Your websocket_urlpatterns is specifying avalible routes. Try connecting to `ws/chat/1` (or `ws/chat/1/` if first is not working)

To add `/ws/` route, add to your websocket_urlpatterns next line

```
path(r'ws/', Experience.as_asgi())
```